# how do I assign read/write/exec permission to my /backup partition?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

when I installed Ubuntu10.04, I create a partition /backup.

After I installed Ubunut, I always failed when I try to put some files into /backup via my account.

I try to assign permission in /etc/fstabm, it also doesn't work.

Any idea to solve this problem via my usual account, not root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created this partition during setup just run `sudo chown <your username> /backup`:to own this directory is simple solution to your problem.